# Use of Ui-route in Angular-2

Tags: angular

I was experimenting on ui-router mainly in angular-2. I am sharing my code with all of you...

app.module.ts :-

```
import {UIRouterModule} from "ui-router-ng2";

let helloState = { name: 'hello', url: '/hello',  component: HelloComponent };

let aboutState = { name: 'about', url: '/about',  component: AboutComponent };

@NgModule({

  imports:[
     UIRouterModule.forRoot({ states: [ helloState, aboutState ], useHash: false })
  ],

  declarations: [ AppComponent, DetailsComponent, HelloComponent, AboutComponent ],

  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]

})
```

app.component.ts :-

```
@Component({

  selector: 'my-app',

  template:`
        <a uiSref="hello" uiSrefActive="active">Hello</a>
        <a uiSref="about" uiSrefActive="active">About</a>
        <ui-view></ui-view>
      `
})

export class AppComponent {}
```

It is working properly..

But my concern is that, I would like to segregate this routing in different page. Like I want to make another page called "uirouting.ts" where I will write all the routing related code and later I just inject it into my app.module.ts

Can any one guide me, How may I do it in static.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a child module which manages your states. Import that into your root application module.

Child module:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { UIRouterModule } from "ui-router-ng2";
import { Hello, About } from "./components";

/** States */
let helloState = { name: 'hello', url: '/hello',  component: Hello }; 
let aboutState = { name: 'about', url: '/about',  component: About };

/** Root Application NgModule */

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    UIRouterModule.forChild({ 
      states: [helloState, aboutState] 
    }),
  ],
  declarations: [ Hello, About ],
})
export class ChildModule {}
```

Route module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule,
    UIRouterModule.forRoot(),
    ChildModule,
  ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
class RootAppModule {}
```

Here's a working example, forked from hello world
https://plnkr.co/edit/2vGIu0N03Qk8MsE6emWV?p=preview